# Drupal: Extract teaser in full view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-themes, drupal-templates

How can I split the teaser from the rest of the content in the node.tpl.php to wrap the teaser text in special markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could preprocess the theme variables to retrieve the teaser and store it separately, otherwise Drupal handles it internally and won't give you a choice.

Here is the code: http://www.mydiary.digiprosoft.com/?p=244 and below are the highlights from that link.

---

In **template.php**

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    // we like to display teasers on the node view pages in a different style,
    // but only if they were NOT set to “show summary on full view” (which seems
    // backward, but the implication with that checkbox is that the teaser is
    // PART of the node’s body, instead of an actual summary of the entire
    // node’s body). if a node’s unbuilt body starts with , then
    // a teaser has been manually set, and “show summary” is not checked.
    if ($variables['page'] == TRUE) { // only do this on full page views.
        $node = node_load($variables['nid']); // we reload the node because
        // by the time it gets here has already been filtered out.
        // this if logic stolen from node.module’s node_teaser_include_verify().
        if (strpos($node->body, '') === 0) {
            $variables['style_teaser_differently'] = TRUE;
            $variables['teaser'] = check_markup($node->teaser, $node->format, FALSE);
        }
    }
}
```

---

In **node.tpl.php**

```
<?php
    if ($style_teaser_differently){
        print '<div class="fullview-teaser">'.$teaser.'<div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: the check for $style_teaser_differently doesn't work. But i can disable them because its another content type with a custom node.tpl.php